# Memory Read Exception when working with 3D-Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

Even though I looked through stackoverflow for this issue for a bit, I couldnt figure out how to solve my problem. I know this a very primitive problem and there are many solutions for similar problems but they didnt help to find a solution.

Its fairly simple:

I allocate a three-dimensional array dynamiclly and the I store the number `2` in each field.

But VS gives me an access-violation.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    

    int width = 512;
    int height = 512;

    int ***colors = (int ***)malloc(width * sizeof(int **));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        colors[i] = (int **)malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            colors[i][j] = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
        }
    }   

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                colors[x][y][z] = 2; //Memory Access Violation happens here

    free(colors);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That's not a 3d array.  That's an array of pointers to an array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays of `int`.  You're also doing absolutely no error checking.

Comment: If you try to move the "store 2" assignment into the appropriate place inside the allocation loop, you will probably see what the problem is.

Comment: Search the web for "casting returnvalue of malloc in C", in short: Don't! Also, turn on warnings in your compiler and see if that gives you anything. Also, just as `malloc()` doesn't operate recursively, `free()` doesn't either. That said, what are the values of `x`, `y` and `z` when your program crashes? If you don't know, you need another invaluable skill, stepping through a program in a debugger. Again, search the web for instructions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got confused with index range for `for` loops.
That is you are not properly allocating the memory thus you will end up accessing out of bound while using it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    colors[i] = (int **)malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        colors[i][j] = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    colors[i] = (int **)malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        colors[i][j] = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Comment: While true, since both `height` and `width` are 512 in the (current) posted code, there's no actual effect from the error.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what about `for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {`?

Comment: Given the outermost pointer is called `color`, I suspect that's a three-element RGB array, and the `for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {` exactly mirrors the `for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)` used to assign values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `width` will act rows, `height` will act as column, then you have allocate `height * width*3`. I'm sorry I can't explain any further :D